# Django - Save a new table1.PK and table2.PK and table2.FK

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I created 2 forms based on django-crispy forms.

1. Form1 shows the OrderHeader
2. Form2 shows the OrderLines in a formset

When i open an existing OrderHeader, i see the Header and the Lines, i can adjust and save the open forms just fine.

When i open the form empty, i select a customer in the OrderHeader and then Add some order lines, but here i can not save as the OrderLine has no FK value for the OrderLine.orderheader.

**Q: How can i save the OrderHeader.pk in the OrderLine.orderheader when i hit submit?**

My views.py

```
def orderline_formset(request, id=None):
    if id:
        orderid = OrderHeader.objects.get(pk=id)
    else:
        orderid = OrderHeader()

    OrderLineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(OrderHeader, OrderLine, OrderLineForm, extra = 1, can_delete=True)  

    form = OrderHeaderForm(instance=orderid)
    formset = OrderLineFormSet(instance=orderid)
    helper = OrderLineFormSetHelper()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        OrderLine.orderheader = orderid
        formset = OrderLineFormSet(request.POST,instance=orderid)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Order saved succesfully!')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Order save error, please check fields below')
    else:
        formset = OrderLineFormSet(instance=orderid)

    return render_to_response("order.html", {'orderform' : form,'formset': formset, 'helper': helper},
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My forms.py

```
class OrderHeaderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderHeaderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False

    class Meta:
        model = OrderHeader


class OrderLineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderLineForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderLine


class OrderLineFormSetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderLineFormSetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.template = 'bootstrap3/table_inline_formset.html'
        self.render_required_fields = True
        self.form_tag = False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that i was only saving the formset and not the form. So i changed my views.py to the following;

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderHeaderForm(request.POST,instance=orderid)
    formset = OrderLineFormSet(request.POST,instance=orderid)
    if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        form.save()
        formset.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Order saved succesfully!')
```